# Flexbox: match height of element, while keeping aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two boxes next to each other in a flex container. One contains an iframe, the other a form. I want the iframe box to match the height of the form box, and have the iframe box keep an aspect ratio of 16:9.

I could not get the old `padding-bottom: 56.25%` trick to work, because that's based on width, which is tricky with Flexbox.

Here's a fiddle with an approximation of my HTML and (S)CSS, if you want to have a stab at this problem. https://jsfiddle.net/7zgh88ew/

If anyone has any ideas, they would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you will have to use js for this.

Answer (score 2):

By using `inline-flex` and a dummy `img` having the correct ratio, set it to `visibility: hidden` and then position the `iframe` absolute, it works, only in Chrome though, so there must be some issue, as with the other browsers, the `img` doesn't size its parent properly.

I will post a question myself to see if someone knows anything about that, and update this post when I know more.

**Update**

For a fixed height, i.e `200px`, one can set it on the `.container` and add `height: 100%` to the `.iframe` and it will work for the other browsers ([solution provided by Tunçel Mert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43185805/2827823))

Still, if the size of the `form-content` is based on its content, it still only appears to work on Chrome.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7zgh88ew/15/)

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 200px;
}

.iframe {
  position: relative;
  height:100%;
  background: red;
}
  .iframe img {
    height:100%;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .iframe iframe {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; 
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

.form {
  background: orange;
}

.fake-form-content {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="iframe">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/160x90">
    <!-- Sorry about the video -->
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" width="320" height="180"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <div class="fake-form-content">
      Fake form content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```